# Echo required attribute from json (dynamic creation of forms) angular

Tags: angularjs, dynamic-forms

I am building my first angularjs app and my project has 3 entities.
I am getting their model in json form.
for example

```
return [
            { "name": "IsActive", "type": "checkbox", "default": "true", "icon": "check" },
            { "name": "Name", "type": "text", "required": "true", "default": "", "icon": "user" },
            { "name": "Email", "type": "email", "validation": "email", "default": "", "icon": "envelope" },
            { "name": "Phone", "type": "text", "default": "", "icon": "phone" },
            { "name": "Fax", "type": "text", "default": "", "icon": "fax" },
            { "name": "Mobile", "type": "text", "default": "", "icon": "mobile" },
            { "name": "Address", "type": "text", "default": "", "icon": "map-marker" },
            { "name": "ContactPerson", "type": "text", "default": "", "icon": "comment" }
        ];
```

With the entities' model i dynamically create their add forms.
Here is part of my html:

```
<div class="addInpRow row" ng-repeat="m in vm.accounts.emodel">
   <input name="{{m.name}}" type="{{m.type}}"/>
 </div>
```

What i want to do is echo the required attribute if it is true.

I have tried several things to print it but nothing does the job.
Some things that i have tried are:

```
<input name="{{m.name}}" {{m.required ? 'required' : ''}} />
<input name="{{m.name}}" aria-required="{{m.required}}" />
```

and many variations of what my m.required looks, like 'required="required".

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<input name="{{m.name}}" ng-required="m.required">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-required`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) instead.

```
<input name={{m.name}} ng-required=m.required>
```